# Is there a known formula for the "cyclicity" of a positive integer?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, abelian-groups

Given a positive integer $n$, let us define that the *cyclicity* of $n$ is the number of multitsets of [cyclic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number_%28group_theory%29) (distinct from $1$) whose product is $n$. For example, the cyclicity of $15$ is $2$, because it can be expressed as a product of cyclic numbers in essentially two distinct ways:

$$15 = 15, \qquad 15 = 5 \times 3$$

> **Question.** Is there a known formula for the "cyclicity" of a positive integer?
>
> Failing that, I'd be happy to learn what identities are known involving the cyclicity function.

Comment: So you wish for analysis of cyclicity only based on product of two numbers to give n?

Comment: For instance, for 8, 8=1x8=2x4, so you'd consider 8's cyclicity to be 0?

Comment: Or since 8=2x2x2, you'd consider its cyclicity to be 1?

Comment: Good question btw +1

Comment: Isn't cyclicity essentially the same as the number of abelian groups of order $n$?

Comment: For prime numbers, $\phi(p)=p-1$. So all prime numbers are cyclic.
The cyclicity of any prime number will be 1. The only even cyclic number is 2; this implies that all numbers divisible by 4 will have a cyclicity of only 1 (The being its prime factorization representation).

Answer (score 2):

Note: Not at all a complete answer.

For prime numbers, $\phi(p)=p-1$. So all prime numbers are cyclic.

---

1. The cyclicity of any prime number will be 1.

   ---
2. The only even cyclic number is 2; this implies that all numbers divisible by 4 will have a cyclicity of only 1 (Excluding its prime factorization representation).